# Visual Studio 2015 Build and Run Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, keyboard, shortcut

In older versions of Visual Studio by pressing CTRL+F5 the C++ project was built and Run after build, automatically.
  In VS 2015 first you need to build the project and then run the project because CTRL+F5 does not compile the project anymore. 
  How can I make the CTRL+F5 shortcut to do both Build+Run a C++ project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, when you press CTRL+F5 Visual Studio asks you if you want to build a changed project:

[image]

It looks like you selected **Do not show this dialog again** and pressed **No**.

To revert it, change HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\General\BuildOutOfDateProjects from 1 to 2.

For all possible values see [__BUILDOUTOFDATEPROJECTS Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.__buildoutofdateprojects.aspx).

**Update** (thanks to Cody Gray): Instead of editing registry, check the **On Run, when projects are out of date** option:

[image]

Comment: You don't need to root around in the registry to change this setting. It is right there in the Visual Studio Options dialog. Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> Build and Run. Do consider updating your answer.

Comment: Thank you, I looked after that option and I could not find it.

Comment: The build dialog seems that is disabled by default in VS2015, that's why I never seen it when pressed CTRL+F5

Comment: This is nice, but depending on your build system it can take VS a long time to work out whether anything needs to be built or not. For that reason, I prefer to keep this setting on 'never build' so I can quickly deploy the program if I haven't made any changes. It would be nice to have a separate 'build and run' setting to use when you *have* made changes.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2017 all I had to do was

<kbd>F5</kbd>

to build and run the project.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019, that starts the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Building: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>

Running: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>F10</kbd>

First Build and then Run